# Azure Website Custom Domain Stopped Working

Tags: asp.net, azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I wrote an ASP.NET MVC Web Application and hosted it with Azure Website.
I used shared instance, north Europe data center and I have added 2 custom domains to it. Website delivers content based on used domain.

- http://budejovickamenuweb.azurewebsites.net/ (default domain which should always return 404)
- http://alza.menu - first variant of website
- http://budejovicka.menu - second variant of website

Everything worked fine for few months.

Then I needed to move website from one subscription to another. I have deleted old website from first account and created it under another (MSDN Premium -> MSDN Ultimate). I set everything same and also added my 2 custom domains. IP address is same as it was before (same data center, confirmed by with Azure portal): 23.100.50.51

**Problem**: Default domain works (main page returns 404 intentionaly and I can also contact WebAPI service so I know it works). But my custom domains don't work at all - it returns generic Azure message `Web App Not Found`: http://alza.menu/

I have tried to:

- access it from different ISP
- flush DNS cache
- wait for few hours
- remove and add my WebSite again
- other custom domain websites work on my account
  ...but it still don't work. So my guess is that it is problem related to deleting old website and creating new with same domains (maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue.
As far as I know it was really problem related to deleting old Website and creating new one with same parameters under new subscription (probably some cache?).

For some reason when I recreated website yesterday there was an original IP address from old website displayed in label "The IP address to use when you configure a records" in "Manage domains" dialog. And this IP address was not correct. But it was probably cached from original Website.

When I opened dialog today IP address was different. When I changed DNS records of my domains to new IP it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is actually related to microsoft servers problems themselves only for today in west europe and north europe. Its not cache or anything they are just having problems with their traffic manager for the next few hours(from my talk with them).
I have deleted the traffic myself and restarted and it worked briefly but then stopped again. So rest assured it will just work fine TOMMOROW.